Sum of nth power of some of the roots of irreducible polynomial over $ \mathbb{Q}$ is in $ \mathbb{Q}$
So i know that for a splitting field K over $ \mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial f(x), where a,b,c,d are the roots of f(x). Taking the following sum $ a^n +b^n+c^n +d^n $ is in the FixGal(K,$ \mathbb{Q}$) . My question is: how about $ a^n +b^n+c^n$? Does that also belong in Q?
I'm thinking that that's not necesarily the case because the previous sum is in Q cause it forms one of the coeficients of the polynomial f(x) which is in $ \mathbb{Q}$[X] while we can't say the same about this one. But i don't know how to prove it

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Maybe, maybe not. For example, if $f(x)=x^4-q$, $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $n=4$, then "yes". On the other hand, if $f(x)=x^4-1$, witth roots $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=i$, $d=-i$, and $n=3$, then $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 = 1-1-i+i=0\in\mathbb{Q}$, but $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 1-1-i=-i\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

@ArturoMagidin thanks for reaching out! So i can just use a counterxample and I'm covered?

Unclear what "I'm covered" means, and you never specified what $n$ was or how it related to $f$ (if in any way). If you are asking "Does this always happen, for any $f$ and $n$?" the answer is no, because there are counterexamples.

@ArturoMagidin the n is not specified, it's for every positive integer n. My question was if its generally true for a splitting field which contains the 4 roots of the polynomial f over Q. I think in that way a counterexample would answer my question and nothing further would be necesarry
